# awk split adds whole string to array position 1 (reason unknown)

Tags: linux, awk

So I have a .txt file that looks like this:

```
mona 70 77 85 77
john 85 92 78 80
andreja 89 90 85 94
jasper 84 64 81 66
george 54 77 82 73
ellis 90 93 89 88
```

I have created a grades.awk script that contains the following code:

```
{
    FS=" "
    names=$1
    vi1=$2
    vi2=$3
    vi3=$4
    rv=$5
    #printf("%s ",names);

    split(names,nameArray," ");
    printf("%s\t",nameArray[1]); //prints the whole array of names for some reason, instead of just the name at position 1 in array ("john")
}
```

So my question is, how do I split this correctly? Am I doing something wrong?

How do you read line by line, word by word correctly. I need to add each column into its own array. I've been searching for the answer for quite some time now and can't fix my problem.

Comment: What you've posted: Input; code that doesn't work. What's missing: Desired output. I.e. what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Perhaps an XY problem.  What are you going to do with the arrays?  Your names array won't include the names, if the data file is single space delimited only one name should appear. I guess your data file is tab separated so `$1==$-0` in your case.

Comment: Like I said in the post, I'm trying to add each column of the grades.txt file into its own array so I can manipulate with the arrays. Example: nameArray would have all of the names (first word of each row), gradesArray1 would have the second column of each row for every element.

The data file is space separated, as I wrote it.

Comment: Based on your posted code, what you observed is not possible. `names` value is replaced with the current first field at each row, so it does not contain the previous values and therefore cannot be split further.  You can easily `names[NR]=$1` to build the names array row by row, similarly for other fields.  However, there might be better methods depending on what you're trying to do.  Better to post the desired output to get better alternatives...

Comment: I need to access the data separately so I can calculate average grade of each student etc. And I have no idea how to access it in awk

Answer (score 0):

here is a template to calculate average grades per student

```
$ awk '{sum=0; for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) sum+=$i; 
        printf "%s\t%5.2f\n", $1, sum/(NF-1)}' file

mona    77.25
john    83.75
andreja 89.50
jasper  73.75
george  71.50
ellis   90.00
```

Comment: Thank you! But I need it in a script, not as a command. I'll try to change it.

Answer (score -1):

```
printf("%s\t",nameArray[1])
```

is doing exactly what you want it to do but you aren't printing any newline between invocations so it's getting called once per input line and outputting one word at a time but since you aren't outputting any newlines between words you just get 1 line of output. Change it to:

```
printf("%s\n",nameArray[1])
```

There are a few other issues with your code of course (e.g. you're setting FS in the wrong place and unnecessarily, names only every contains 1 word so splitting it into an array doesn't make sense, etc.) but I think that's what you were asking about specifically.

If that's not all you want then edit your question to clarify what you're trying to do and add concise, testable sample input and expected output.

Comment: Where should I set the FS then? I need to access the data separately so I can calculate average grade of each student etc. And I have no idea how to access it in awk

Comment: @Yanketz if you did have to set FS you'd do it in the BEGIN section but you don't have to set it as your data is separated by the default value.